# Rails Admin - Show field even when blank in show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm using rails admin, and I need to display fields in the show action if they are blank as well as if they are populated.

```
show do
  field :name
  field :key
  field :description
  field :type
end
```

At the moment, if description is empty (which is allowed) it will only display name, and fields.
I need it to display all 3 fields regardless of if they are populated or not.

Update: Pictures

Example with empty description field:

[image: empty desc]

Example with populated description field:

[image: pop desc]

Thanks

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of a screen with and another without the field. I don’t understand what you expect to see

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba I have now updated the question with pictures, please let me know what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever rails admin detects a falsy value it does not show the field, so an empty string or nil would hide it.
You have to give it a non falsy value as a default like this

```
show do
  field :name
  field :key
  field :type
  field :description
    formatted_value do
      value || '-'
    end
  end
end
```